# Scroll helper for mobile website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, web-applications, scroll

I have a very long article page that I want to help mobile users scroll on. For very long lists in mobile apps there's usually a alphabetical index that can help users jump to various places in the list. How do I implement something like that for a webapp?

If it helps my stack is angularjs / jquery / phonegap.

Comment: We would love if you could come and check some proposed solution before the time expires, since you opened a bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## iOS7 Style List Navigator

If you want something nice on the phone, I just wrote this iOS7 style list navigator. I think the way Apple solved the problem is very straightforward. So we steal it.

It's written considering that you won't probably scroll the body, because in the many designs I've seen for smartphones, scrolling a container allows you to have fixed headers and footers for Android < 4 without getting mad.

A word of warning: this code is really fresh and untested.

[SEE DEMO AND CODE](http://codepen.io/frapporti/pen/GtaLD)

#### CSS (extract)

```
#scrolling {
    padding-top: 44px;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scroll: touch;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 58px;
}

.list .divider {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* will stop the label when it reaches the header */
    top: 44px;
}
```

#### HTML (extract)

```
<div id="scrolling">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
    <!-- etc -->
</ul>
<ul class="list">
   <li class="divider" id="a">A</li>
   <li><a href="#">Amelia Webster</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Andrew WifKinson</a></li>
   <!-- etc -->
```

### Javascript (zepto/jquery)

```
$(function() { 
  $(window).on("touchstart touchmove mouseover click", ".menu a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clearInterval(t);
    var steps = 25;
    var padding =  68;
    var target = $( $(this).attr("href") ).next("li");
    if ( target.length > 0 ) {
        var scroller = $("#scrolling")[0];
        var step = parseInt((target[0].offsetTop - padding - scroller.scrollTop)/steps);
        var stepno = 0;
            setInterval( function() {
                if ( stepno++ <= steps  ) {
                    scroller.scrollTop += step;
                } else {
                    clearInterval(t)
                }
            }, 20);
    };
  });
});
```

It performs a basic check of link validity before attempting the scroll. You can change padding to your needs.

Also, you will notice that we are targeting the first element after the required target. This is because Safari seems to go nuts because of the sticky positioning.

This code uses jQuery/Zepto selectors for the sake of brevity and readability. But these libraries are not really needed to achieve the result. With just a little extra digitation you could easily go dependency-free.

http://codepen.io/frapporti/pen/GtaLD

Comment: mmhh just tested on mobile, doing some fix

Comment: it's fine in iphone, less in browser.. needs a little extra work

Comment: ok, done a few corrections now, need to check how it is behaving in different android versions. any volunteer?

Comment: @Francesco Frapporti I have tried your solution for my phonegap application for android device as i need to implement the same feature but this didn't work on that. After click on any alphabet, it wasn't navigating anywhere. Will you plz provide any solution for android device to implement this plz? it would be helpfull to me. Thanks

Comment: If it's phonegap we could have different issues coming up.. I'll give it a shot, but if we get to do too much in the comments here I'd advice you to open another question so we've got more room and more people come to help. Questions: 1. are you embedding the external library (zepto or jquery)? 2. version of android and of phonegap 3. is external network connection enabled in the project settings? 4.can you try it in the browser and see if anything changes?

Comment: I am using Jquery Mobile framework. Targeted Version of android 2.2 and above and 1.9.0 version of phonegap. Yes external network connection enabled in the project setting. I have tried it in browser it works fine there but the scrolling didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution with iscroll.js but when i implement that scrolling work perfectly but after click on any alphabet it was not navigating to that list divider. Any help from your side would be greatly appreciated and it will be helpful to me

Answer (score 3):

Just use angular's built-in `$anchorScroll` service.

See the [live example in angular's official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24anchorScroll). Here are the important pieces of code:

#### In your view template:

```
<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollCtrl">
  <a ng-click="gotoBottom()">Go to bottom</a>
  <a id="bottom"></a> You're at the bottom!
</div>
```

#### In your controller:

```
function ScrollCtrl($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.gotoBottom = function (){
    // set the location.hash to the id of
    // the element you wish to scroll to.
    $location.hash('bottom');

    // call $anchorScroll()
    $anchorScroll();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a toggleable sidebar like [this](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar.html) one. Resize your browser to the width of the screen of a mobile phone to understand what I mean.

Then create a directive in angularjs to wrap jQuery's animate function to scroll to a specific part in the article. Like this:

```
angular.module('yourModule', [])
       .directive('scrollTo', function() {
          return {
           restrict : 'EA',
           link: function(scope , element, attr){
                   $('html, body').animate({
                      scrollTop: $( attr['href'] ).offset().top
                    }, 300);
                 }
          };
       });
```

where href will be an id of a specific section in the article. Then all you need to do is apply the directive to the links in the sidebar.

```
... 
<li><a href="#section-1" scroll-to>Jump to section 1</a></li>
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that's pretty helpful, but the UI is much more cumbersome than what's traditional on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for http://www.designkode.com/alphascroll-jquery-mobile/

Haven't used it myself, but seems pretty simple to get going with.

Comment: Unfortunate jquery mobile dependency, I am looking for something like that, hopefully not limited to alphabetical lists and not dependent on jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this could work for you: http://codepen.io/aecend/pen/AsnIE. This is just a basic prototype I put together to answer but I could expand on the concept if needed. Basically, it creates a translucent bar on the right side of the screen, finds each of the headings for articles (which would need to be adapted to suit your needs) and places clickable/tappable anchors to jump to individual articles. When you click one, the page scrolls to that article. I have a few ideas to make this actually usable, but here's the proof of concept.

**CSS**

```
#scrollhelper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scrollhelper .point {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var articles;

function buildScrollHelp() {
    var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
    var viewHeight = window.innerHeight;

    $("#scrollhelper").html("");

    articles.each(function() {
        var top = $(this).offset().top;
        var element = document.createElement("a");
        element.className = "point";
        element.href = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
        element.style.top = ((top / bodyHeight) * viewHeight) + "px";
        $(element).on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
             }, 500);
        });

        $("#scrollhelper")[0].appendChild(element);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    articles = $("body").children("[id]");
    $("body").append("<div id=\"scrollhelper\"></div>");

    $(window).resize(function(){
        buildScrollHelp();
    });

    buildScrollHelp();

});
```