# Angularjs - auto-scroll to location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ui-router with Angularjs and I would like to know how to make the screen scroll down (hopefully with easing to make it look better) to a specific part of my homepage when a user clicks on a link. I would also like it to scroll when someone clicks on a link from another page too.

The only examples I can find on here are about scrolling automatically to the ui-view which is not what I want. Other examples include ng-route which is not what I'm using.

Is there a feature built in to Angular/ui-router to help with this or should I just use what I have from another of my sites that doesn't use Angular:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var target = this.hash,
  $target = $(target);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
  }, 900, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
  });
});
```

Any advice/code much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to use ui-router for that. You have to wrap that code into a directive in angularjs. Check my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657542/scroll-helper-for-mobile-website/23659749#23659749).

Comment: Thanks - so what would the links look like then because at the moment I am using `ui-sref`

Comment: and how would it scroll coming from another page

Comment: Ahhh, you didn't specify that the user is coming from another page. I thought you wanted to scroll in the same page. I don't know for sure but you can try and pass the hash as a parameter to the state you are navigating to and use that in the animate function (or just change the window's location).

Comment: well I did actually but no problem - thanks for the advice anyway

Comment: in angular to use an anchor links you can use ##. i.e. <a href="/page##anchor">Go To Anchor</a>